# Difficulties summing infinite exponential series

Tags: probability

I was thinking about a problem in computer science that lead me towards some confusion with math.

Let's assume I want to generate 4 numbers between $[1, 6]$, with no duplicate numbers. Also let's assume I'm using this algorithm for generating a new number:

```
1. generate random number
2. if I already picked this generated number:
2.1 return to (1.)
```

Also let's assume I have already shuffled 3 correct numbers out of the 4 I need. The complexity is about $\Theta(\infty)$ for the worst case (as I'm not guaranteed I will ever pick a random number that satisfies the condition of `2.`), and the best case complexity is $\Theta(1)$ as it is possible that my first random will be alright and will yield a satisfying number.

But, what about the average case? I wanted to know, on average, what is the number of random numbers I'd have to generate in order to satisfy the condition.

*Now for the math part:*

The probability of generating a number which satisfies the condition is exactly $P_s=\frac12$, as we have 3 satisfying options out of 6 possible options (which are the 3 options that are not the previous 3 numbers we chose).

Now, the probability for failing $n$ times should be $(P_f)^n=(1-P_2)^n=\frac 1 {2^n}$. So the probability of succeeding after $n$ times should be the probability for failing $n-1$ times, then succeeding: $P=(P_f)^{n-1}*P_s=\frac 1 {2^{n-1}}*\frac12=\frac 1 {2^n}$

I receive a function for the probability of succeeding in the $n$th try, call it $f(n)=\frac 1 {2^n}$.

Now I want to find the average value of this function for all possibilities of $n$ from 1 to $\infty$, then find the $n$ that $f(n)=\bar f([1,\infty])$

Where I got confused? The sum of probabilities over the whole domain of events should be 1 (because **something** must happen, right?).

<s>So I summed up the infinite function from 1 to $\infty$:</s> So I integrated the function, which seems like is an incorrect approach.

$$\int_1^\infty\frac 1 {2^n} dn=\int_1^\infty2^{-n} dn=\left[ \frac 1 {\ln(2)} * -1 * 2 ^{-n} \right]_1^\infty=\left[ \frac {-1} {2^n\ln(2)} \right]_1^\infty=\frac {-1} {2^{\infty}\ln(2)}-\frac {-1} {2^1\ln(2)}=0+\frac 1 {2\ln(2)}\neq1$$

How do I sum this series correctly?

Comment: You should be summing, not integrating.  This is a series, not a function on the real numbers.

Comment: So my problem is actually different than understanding, it's more technical now. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward geometric distribution: The probability that it takes $k$ selections, for $k \geq 1$, is (as you note in your question)

$$
p_k = \left(\frac12\right)^k
$$

If you add up all these probabilities, you get

$$
\frac12 + \frac14 + \frac18 + \cdots = 1
$$

If you require a proof of this last statement, please indicate the level of rigor you'd like.  But as you suspected, the probabilities do add up to $1$.

---

I'm not sure why you would want the expected value of $p_k$.  That would be

$$
\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac1N \sum_{k=1}^N p_k = 0
$$

But you might very well want the expected value of $K$, the random variable representing the number of selections needed.  That would be

\begin{align}
E(K) & = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kp_k \\
     & = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty k\left(\frac12\right)^k \\
     & = \frac{1/2}{(1/2-1)^2} \\
     & = 2
\end{align}

That is to say, it takes two selections to select just the fourth and last of the numbers.  If you want a proof of that, the same conditions apply. :-)

Comment: Alight. For everything above the line, I obviously must be missing some cups of coffee for missing this. Ugh. For everything below the line, thanks, seems like valuable information, and I'll have to make my research about that. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain how you reached the last $E(K)$ expression?

Comment: @YotamSalmon: There are a number of ways to convince yourself that $S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k = \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, provided you know that $T = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k = \frac{x}{1-x}$.  One way is to break the former sum up into $S = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k+(k-1)x^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k + \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)x^k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k + x\sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)x^{k-1} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k + x\sum_{k=0}^\infty kx^k =  \sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k + x\sum_{k=1}^\infty kx^k$ (because the $k = 0$ term is $0$).  Then identify this last equation as $S = T+xS$, and solve algebraically for $S$.